# There is written of this question's correct answer is (B). Is it right, if so then why?

Tags: conditionals

There is written of this question's correct answer is (B). Is it right, if so then why?

> If he ___ in Tokyo he ___ us.
> A) was / will visit
> B) were / would visit
> C) will be / will visit
> D) is / would visit
> E) are / will visit

Comment: Yes, it is B. This is a subjunctive mood in English grammar known as the "were-subjunctive." Check out this link for a fuller explanation: https://www.merriam-webster.com/words-at-play/getting-in-the-subjunctive-mood

Comment: Okay, sir. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**A) was / will visit**
"Was" is the past tense and "will" is the future tense. The tenses do not match, and the sentence does not make sense.

**B) were / will visit**
Here the [subjunctive mood](https://www.merriam-webster.com/words-at-play/getting-in-the-subjunctive-mood) is used. The sentence makes sense: He *would* visit us if he were to be in Tokyo, but he is not in Tokyo, so he does not visit.

**C) will be / will visit**
I think this answer could work... but it sounds a little awkward to me, which is probably an indication that it doesn't really work. Perhaps someone else will explain to me why it doesn't.

**D) is / would visit**
"Is" is the present tense while "would" is the conditional that *should* go with a subjunctive.

**E) are / will visit**
"He" is singular, but "are" is plural, so there is a mismatch.

Comment: Okay, Thank you very much! :)